# issue in Date and month select list using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

little new in jquery. I am creating two list boxes using jquery. one contain date and other contain months. Both are used in different places in my html page. so i am try to put it in a function

but this is not working. http://jsfiddle.net/mVR6g/4/

```
      <div class="drop">
       <div style="float:left;">Date of Birth : &nbsp;</div>
       <div class="current"><input type="text"  name="Mem_DOB" class="memdate1"/></div>
     <div class="alldate1"></div> <div class="allmonth1"></div>
    </div> 

      <div class="drop">
       <div style="float:left;">Wedding Anniversery : &nbsp;</div>
       <div class="current"><input type="text"  name="Mem_WAnn" class="memdate2"/></div>
     <div class="alldate2"></div> <div class="allmonth2"></div>
    </div>


$(document).ready(function () {
 $('.memdate1').click(function () {
    var date = $('.alldate1').attr('id');
    alert(date);
    var month = $('allmonth1').attr('id'); 
    Genratecalender(date, month);
});
$('.memdate2').click(function () {
    var date = $('.alldate1').attr('id');
    alert(date);
    var month = $('allmonth2').attr('id'); 
    Genratecalender(date, month);
});

function Genratecalender(date,month) {
    var arr = []
    for (var i = 1; i < 32; i++) {
        arr.push({ val: i, text: i })
    }
    var sel = $('<select>');
    $(arr).each(function () {
        sel.append($("<option>").attr('value', this.val)
            .text(this.text));
    });
    $('.div'+ date).html(sel);
    $('.div'+ date).show();
    //month list
    var arr = [
        { val: 'January', text: 'January' },
        { val: 'February', text: 'February' },
        { val: 'March', text: 'March' },
        { val: 'April', text: 'April' },
        { val: 'May', text: 'May' },
        { val: 'June', text: 'June' },
        { val: 'July', text: 'July' },
        { val: 'August', text: 'August' },
        { val: 'September', text: 'September' },
        { val: 'October', text: 'October' },
        { val: 'November', text: 'November' },
        { val: 'December', text: 'December' },
    ];
    var sel = $('<select>');

    $(arr).each(function () {
        sel.append($("<option>").attr('value', this.val)
            .text(this.text));
    });

    $('.div' + month).html(sel);
    $('.div' + month).show();
    //$('.memdate').hide();$("div#" + name).
}
```

});

Comment: You need to include jQuery to your jsFiddle

Comment: DOM with class `alldate1` name does not have ID attribute...

Comment: @DipeshParmar: then how can i solve this..

Answer (score 0):

**Replace**

```
var date = $('.alldate1').attr('id');
```

**with**

```
var date = $(this).val();
```

because you do not have ID attribute defined for `DOM`.

Comment: but this shows nothing. and actully i want to add the list into alldate1

Comment: @Parvathiiiii can you please update fiddle with full HTML code

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mVR6g/8/ updated. actualy i need that when clicked on the input box, hide that and show the month list and date list